# How to prevent tags from becoming separated by white-space?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm generating a XML document that will be parsed as XHTML using XDocument. In some parts of it I have lists formated as:

```
 <root>
    <div>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </div>
 </root>
```

The whitespace between `<div>` and `<span>` (and respective terminators) is messing up my CSS. Is it possible to force it to NOT insert white-space in those cases, generating something like:

```
 <root>
    <div><span>Item 1</span></div>
    <div><span>Item 2</span></div>
 </root>
```

`SaveOptions.DisableFormatting` does work, but then it becomes a pain to (human) read the file. So I need something else.

Comment: In this kind of case... I would just fix the CSS. Whitespace isn't supposed to mess it up like that

Comment: Nothing to fix there, a `div::after{ content: ": #";}` instruction will insert content inside the div at the end before the closing that, this is how pseudo-selectors work. If you have whitespace between the terminators then the `": #"` would have a space between it. And I can't use a `span::after` due to other manipulations being done to it too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer, I will leave it here for others to comment and find possible bugs before accepting it.

I inserted a blank `XText` as the first element in the div and made XDocument understand it as mixed content (or something like that) and produce the output that I need.

```
div.AddFirst(new XText(""));
```

Does anyone have documentation on why it doesn't format mixed content and if that is indeed what is happening?

BTW, it has to be a empty XText, just the below doesn't work:

```
div.AddFirst("");
```